# How to get a value of dictionaries and nested dictionaries within a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
example_dict = [({'Progrm':'Python'},
                 {'Rohit':{'age':24,'pincode':400000}},
                 {'Rahul':{'age':22,'pincode':500000}})]
```

I would like to get the above program output as only values of dict and nested dict:

```
Python
age:24, pincode : 400000
24
400000
age:22, pincode : 500000
22
500000
```

How can I access the values?

Comment: Are these really one-element dicts inside a tuple inside a one-element list?? There are deeper problems with your data structure

Comment: Some [research effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) is expected from you.

Comment: To those doing data-structure bashing ... something like this is guaranteed to be 'inefficient' in python, so without offering an example of what the data structure SHOULD look like you're just belching hot air.  It's cool I guess, as this question shouldn't really even be here, but still.

Comment: @DarrenRinger fair enough. This should all be one dictionary if order doesn't matter, or one `collections.OrderedDict` if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Well `example_dict` is a one-element list, so:

```
the_tuple = example_dict[0] # ({'Progrm':'Python'}, ...)
for dct in the_tuple:
    for value in dct.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print(", ".join(["{}:{}".format(k,v) for k,v in value.items()]))
            for v in value.values():
                print(v)
        else:
            print(value)
```

Results in:

```
Python
age:24, pincode:400000
24
400000
age:22, pincode:500000
22
500000
```

Or more comically:

```
"\n".join(["\n".join([", ".join(["{}:{}".format(k,v) for k,v in value.items()])]+[str(v) for v in value.values()]) if isinstance(value, dict) else value for tup in example_dict for dct in tup for value in dct.values()])
```